# Why won't "\t" create a tab?

Tags: java, string, indentation, bluej

I want the `"Module Code = "` and `"Result = "` to be separated by a tab but whenever I run the code below it literally just outputs

```
"Module Code = Biology\tResult = 40.0"
```

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Module Code = " + moduleCode + "\t" + "Result = " + result;

}
```

Comment: "\t" is a tabulation, not a new line. New line is "\n".

Comment: If it's in single quotes, it's a character: char tabChar = '\t'; if it's in double quotes, it's just an escaped t.

Comment: @Kylar: No, that's not true at all. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Comment: Try `"Module Code = " + moduleCode + ((char)0x9) + "Result = " + result`.

Comment: You already have a tab. However, how that tab is *rendered* will depend on what you do with the string - and you haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: @aleb2000: That will behave *exactly* the same way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you outputting this? Could your output device be re-"escaping" the tabulation character into the sequence `\t`?

Comment: Well, I've tested printing with BlueJ and it works just fine with "\t". I guess you've either somehow altered the configuration of the console, though I neither know where or how, or print the `String` in a specific way

Comment: The return String literally needs to print "Module Code = (user inputted value) TAB "Result = (user inputted double value);  If I have accidentally altered the configuration, do you know how I can change it back?

Comment: @J.Doe It may be a problem with the device that renders the output. Where are you rendering it? Console? IDE output window? Something else?

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis I'm sorry, I'm a noob so I'm not exactly sure what the output window is called!. Here's a screenshot https://postimg.org/image/nats0osrh

Comment: @J.Doe That window in BlueJ may not support tabulation at all, so it prints the tabulation as `\t`. I think if you print it to the console (using `System.out.println`) you will get the result you want.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis My course assignment says the method must be called  `Public String toString()` but this type of method needs a return statement. If I use `System.out.println` I just get the error "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String" I can only use the `System.out.println` statement with a void method to avoid the error. What do I do?

Comment: Don’t put the print statement into the `toString()` method. Use it, e.g., where you create an instance of the class having that `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're viewing the value of the produced string in the BlueJ window. That window is good for debugging purposes, but it won't exhibit the same behavior that a proper output device would, especially with respect to characters such as newline, tabulation, etc. Those characters will still appear with their escape sequences, just like you typed them in your source code.

In other words, your `toString()` method is fine and it works as intended. If you want to see its results formatted properly, don't view them using BlueJ -- print them somewhere else. The console is a good choice:

```
System.out.println(module.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why won't **“\t”** create a new line?

well, that is because **“\t”** is a tabulation not a new line **“\n”**

if you need a  new line try instead

```
return "Module Code = " + moduleCode + "\n" + "Result = " + result;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I changed the title. I need a tab, not a new line. How can I get "\t" to work?